# Eisenstein criterion's condition

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Proposition: If the constant term is $1$ or $-1$, then we can't use the Eisenstein criterion to determine whether the polynomial is irreducible over $Q$.

Is it right?

---

#### Edit

Since directly use is not right.
So the proposition is right or not right?

And further question is, ***When should I*** try some substitutions to use Eisenstein criterion? Any guidelines and rules?

For example，I found two examples：

$x^7+7x+1$

Comment: [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) requires that the constant term be a multiple of some prime number $p$. The numbers $\pm 1$ are the only ones that do not have a prime factor.

Comment: Yes, if the constant term is $1$ then we cannot use Eisenstein directly to prove irreducibility, since there is no prime we could apply it with.

Comment: However, as the wikipedia link @lhf put forward points out under Examples - Cyclotomic polynomials, substituting $x$ for $(x-1)$ or $(x+1)$ and expanding the brackets, might just make a suitable prime pop out on the other end. Any other substitute $(x+a)$ for an integer $a$ might also work, so while it might be long and tedious to calculate, it might just be worth it in the end.

Comment: Sometimes (but rarely) a substitution helps, e.g. $f(x)=x^4+4x^3+10x^2+12x+7$ becomes, after $x\mapsto x+1$, $g(x)=x^4+4x^2+2$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein.

Comment: @DietrichBurde When can I try the substitution, is there any rules?

Comment: Yes, for example with $x^3+x+1$ a substitution is useless, see the answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458802/irreducibility-check-for-polynomials-not-satisfying-eisenstein-criterion.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already some answer here: [Irreducibility check for polynomials not satisfying Eisenstein Criterion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458802/irreducibility-check-for-polynomials-not-satisfying-eisenstein-criterion)
In addition, there are some results on how many 
monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be shown to be irreducible by Eisenstein's crtiterion. For example, less that $1\%$ of the polynomials with at least seven non-zero coefficients are irreducible by Eisenstein (A. Dubickas, 2003).

Edit: To the new question. No, if the constant term is $\pm 1$, we cannot apply Eisenstein directly, and also not in general after a substitution $x\mapsto x+a$ (e.g., $x^3+x+1$). And yes, there are certain rules, called Eisenstein shifts, when you can attempt a substitution. See the article "On shifted Eisenstein polynomials" of R Heyman, I. Shparlinski (2013).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can't use Eisenstein directly, but you might be able to after a substitution.

Comment: Yes, but the substitutions you might perform are quite limited, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458802/irreducibility-check-for-polynomials-not-satisfying-eisenstein-criterion.

Comment: When can I try the substitution, is there any rules?