# Irreducibility of polynomials over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

If I want to show that a certain polynomial is irreducible over a finite field, which methods do I have?

In particular how can I show that $X^4-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_5$

The idea which I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147706/irreducibility-of-a-polynomial-with-degree-4) does not work very well for me.

Its not hard to see that the polynomial has no roots in the finite field. So the only possibility being reducible is that I can split it into two polynomials with degree $2$.

Should I try it as usual with $x^4-3=x^4-2x^2+9=(a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1)(a_2x^2+b_1x+c_1)$?

I tried it, but didn't came to a solution. Can someone help me?

Comment: There are fortunately not many irreducible polynomials of degree 2 over this field.

Comment: Duke, take a look at [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/353233/11619). That polynomial remains irreducible over the bigger field $\Bbb{F}_{125}$. Fortunately the proof of irreduciblity is the same: The zeros of this quartic are of order sixteen, and the field $\Bbb{F}_{5^4}$ is the smallest extension containing such elements. The usefulness of that argument depends on you being familiar with a few things about finite fields. Therefore I won't mark this as a duplicate. At least not yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

You have that $-3=2$ in $\mathbb F_5$. Therefore you just have to try to find $b,c\in\mathbb F_5$ such that

$$X^4-3=X^4+2=(X^2+bX+1)(X^2+cX+2),$$
or
$$X^4-3=X^2+2=(X^2+bX+3)(X^2+bX+4),$$

and if you get a contradiction, $X^4-3$ is not a product of two polynomial of degree 2. To check that it's not a product of polynomials of degree 1 and 3, you just have to show that for all $a\in \mathbb F_5$, 
$$a^4+2\neq 0,$$
which is very quick.

**Added**

$$X^4+2=(X^2+bX+1)(X^2+cX+2)$$
$$\iff X^4+2=X^4+(b+c)X^3+(3+bc)X^2+(2b+c)X+2$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}b+c=0\\ 3+bc=0\\2b+c=0\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}b=-c\\c^2=3\\c=0\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}b=c=0\\
c^2=3\end{cases}$$

The contradiction is that if $c=0$, $c^2\neq 3$.

Now do the same reasoning with $X^4-3=(X^2+bX+3)(X^2+cX+4)$ and you'll get a contradiction too (if it's really irreducible).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I know this, but I was not able to get a contradiction.

Comment: I completed my answer.