# Transforming a Polynomial to Show Irreducibility Using Eisenstein's Criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have a particular polynomial

$$z^5-5z^4+30z^3-150z^2+465z-725$$

A quick check in mathematica shows that this polynomial is irreducible over the rationals, however, it does not pass the third condition of Eisenstein's Criteria to prove it definitively.  Unfortunately, $$5^2|725$$

My question is this.  I know you can make a transformation $z=x-c$ and once the transformed polynomial can be shown by EC to be irreducible then the original polynomial is irreducible.  What is a suitable value for $c$ and is there a definitive or canonical approach to determining the  possible value of $c$?

Comment: Try $c=1$. Then we obtain $x^5 - 10x^4 + 60x^3 - 280x^2 + 880x - 1376$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde As I understand he want backwards reasoning for the choice of c

Comment: Is there a way to determine the $c$?  Guess?

Comment: You can do even rational substitutions, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673805/satisfying-eisensteins-criterion-by-rational-function-substitution). It does not always work, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For a polynomial of $n$.degree and a coefficient $a_{n-1}\neq 0$. You can always reduce the $(n-1)$-power by $z=x+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}$.

As Dietrich Burde suggested $c=1$ for this case.

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no suitable value for $c$. This has been shown at the answers to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849823/eisensteins-criterion-stronger-version), with the example
$$
f(x) = x^3 + x + 1\in \mathbb{Z}[x].
$$