# When can Eisenstein's Criterion never be used?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If $R$ is a UFD and $f \in R[x]$, then we can't always use Eisenstein's Rule directly to show that $f$ is irreducible in Frac$(R)[x]$. However if we have $\phi$, an automorphism of Frac$(R)[x]$, then $f$ is irreducible if and only if $\phi(f)$ is irreducible. In order to apply Eisenstein to the resulting polynomial, you need $\phi(f) \in R[x]$, then you can deduce that your original $f$ was irreducible (we are using a 'shifted' version of the rule).

For example, for the cyclotomic polynomials $x^{p-1} + \dots + x + 1$, you cannot use Eisenstein directly, however if you consider $\phi : \mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x]$ which sends $x$ to $x+1$ and does nothing on $\mathbb{Q}$, then using the binomial the resulting polynomial is Eisenstein at $p$.

> What I am wondering is given an irreducible polynomial, can you always find an automorphism such that you can apply Eisenstein to show it's irreducible?
>   If not in general then what about the case where $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458802/irreducibility-check-for-polynomials-not-satisfying-eisenstein-criterion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a family of examples I like very much.

Assume that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ are chosen in such a way that $a,b,ab$ are not squares. Then the polynomial $f_{a,b}=X^2-2(a+b)X^2+(a-b)^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, but you can show that for any prime $p$, and for all $u\in \mathbb{Z}$, $ f_{a,b}(X+u)$ is not $p$-Eisenstein, and is reducible modulo $p$.

Then the usual criteria for irreducibilty do not apply.

Comment: What about $f_{a,b}(wX + u)$ for $w,u \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? If you can prove this is irreducible then the first will be too.

Comment: it is not p-Eisenstein either for all $p\nmid w$ (which is necessary anayway to a $p$-Eisenstein) Same for irreducibility mod $p$.